# run php function and launch page in same table row press?

Tags: php, html

I Know how to launch a new php page and run a function on a table row press, but can you do both at the same time? for some context I want to press a table row with data I have from a data base on `index.php` and launch `Form.php`. And then when pressed I also want to call `function getIndexRow` to get the id of the row in the database so I can then display all the data from the one row on `Form.php`. also, I have tried using `include("Form.php")` but my css collide and make `index.php` look bad. so, without use `include` would be nice.

```html
    <tbody>
        <?php
            include("DBLookupQuerys.php"); 
            while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($Fullsql)) {
                ?> <tr >
                <?php
                echo '<td>'. $rows['Item ID'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $rows['Accession #'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $rows['Name'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>' ?> <img class="Img_Table" src="Images/<?php echo      $rows['img']; ?>" alt="no Image" > <?php echo '</td>'; ?> <?php
                echo '<td>'. $rows['OnDisplay'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $rows['Room #'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $rows['Shelf #'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $rows['Row #'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $rows['Missing'] .'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: It sounds like you'd want the button you press in the table row to be a link to `Form.php` which should be setup to accept the the row index as a `GET` variable. For example: `Form.php?IndexRow=$i`

Comment: I just added a sample of my code could you show me what it may look like. if you dont mind?

Comment: "_I know how to launch a new php page and run a function on a table row press_" -- I don't see your code doing either of those two?

Comment: oh. I didnt add it yet im also somewhat new so what i meant was if you could edit it so I can see what had to be changed.

Comment: Surely just a hyperlink in the row, like `echo '<td><a href="Form.php?id='.$rows['Item ID'] .'>View Details</a></td>';` so it sends the ID to the new page in the URL. Then in Form.php you can use `$id = $_GET["id"];` to put the ID into a variable and use it in your script (for example so you can fetch the item details from the database and display them). This is all pretty standard web application stuff, it should be explained in lots of tutorials etc already.